# better implementation of one hot encoding in python

Tags: python, function, one-hot-encoding

We were assigned a certain problem for school as an introduction to one-hot encoding. We simply have to make a function called `onehot_encode` that accepts a list as a parameter. If however, there are two distinct values only, drop the first column then.

My function looks like this:

```
def onehot_encode(cat_values):
    """
    Return one-hot encoded values from a list of categorical values

    Parameters
    ----------
    cat_values : list, str
        list of categorical values

    Returns
    -------
    pandas DataFrame :
        one-hot encoded values
    """
    y = pd.get_dummies(pd.Series(cat_values))
    df = pd.DataFrame(y)
    if len(y.columns) == 2:
        df = df.drop(df.columns[0], axis=1)
        return df
    else:
        return df
```

These are the parameters to be used:

```
onehot_encode(['m', 'm', 'f', 'f']).astype(int)
onehot_encode(['a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'd', 'e'])
```

The output if the parameter is `onehot_encode(['m', 'm', 'f', 'f']).astype(int)`:

```
  m
0 1
1 1
2 0
2 0
```

The output if the parameter is `onehot_encode(['a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'd', 'e'])`:

```
  a b c d e
0 1 0 0 0 0
1 1 0 0 0 0
2 0 1 0 0 0
3 0 0 1 0 0
4 1 0 0 0 0 
5 0 0 0 1 0
6 0 0 0 0 1
```

This completely works. But is there a better way of implementing this? I wanna do away with if-else statements.

Comment: post your expected output. looks like your code is not doing one-hot encoding it's just removing the duplicates

Comment: Hi! I was asking merely for a better implementation but yes, I edited my question with the output it shows.

Comment: expected output for this `['a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'd', 'e']` and do you want output as a list or dataframe?

Comment: hi! I edited my output for this again. thanks for pointing this out!